# How to push response data redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

so the idea is everytime i click the button it will dispatch my action,and i want to push my response data into an array, but it always overwrite an exising array, how do i fix it?

this is my code

```js
function searchApiPhoto(param, page) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'api-token',
    },
  }
  return axios
    .get(apiurl, config)
    .then((res) => {
      let data = []
      // let result = [];
      // console.log("data :", res.data.results);
      // data = [...res.data.results];
      // data.push(...res.data.results);
      data.push(res.data.results)
      console.log('datas =>', data)
      // return result;
      return res.data.results
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are declaring `data` inside the `.then()` callback. When the callback is over, the variable will be cleared...you need to define that array outside the function and return it